# Duplicate Entry in listview

Tags: c#, listview, duplicates

Uhmm... Excuse me can anybody help... I'm trying to compare if item already existing in listview, but first when I add an item it's okay. But when I change the item then add the item it still says duplicate entry. What I want to do is when every time I add an item it will detect if item is already in listview. Thanks in advance!!

```
while (myReadersup1.Read())
        {
            string item = myReadersup1.GetString("ProdName");
            string price = myReadersup1.GetFloat("ProdPrice").ToString("n2");
            string noi = cmbNOI.SelectedItem.ToString();
            bool alreadyInList = false;

                foreach (ListViewItem itm in lvCart.Items)
                {

                    if (lvCart.Items.Cast<object>().Contains(itm))
                    {
                        alreadyInList = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Entry!");
                        break;

                    }

                }
                if (!alreadyInList)
                {
                    lvCart.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { item, price, noi }));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, you need an else that will set alreadyInList to false if the item isn't found. Otherwise, it's always true.

Answer (score 0):

As you foreach through the current items, you are checking to see if it is in the items collection, and that will always be true.  You may want to change it to something similar:

```
    private bool AddListViewItem(string item, string price, string noi)
    {
        if (this.DetectDuplicate(item, price, noi))
            return false;

        string[] content = new string[] { item, price, noi };
        ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem();
        newItem.Content = content;
        _listView.Items.Add(newItem);
        return true;
    }

    private bool DetectDuplicate(string item, string price, string noi)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvwItem in _listView.Items)
        {
            string[] itemContent = lvwItem.Content as string[];
            Debug.Assert(itemContent != null);
            if (itemContent[0].Equals(item) &&
                itemContent[1].Equals(price) &&
                itemContent[2].Equals(noi))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```